# error LNK1120: 192 unresolved externals

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013

Hi im trying to run open source c++ code for tracking object using webcam 
and i face this problen while building the project 
im using visual studio 2013

The error is as following

```
Error   432 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "extern "C" struct _IplImage * __cdecl cvCreateImage(struct CvSize,int,int)" (?cvCreateImage@@$$J0YAPAU_IplImage@@UCvSize@@HH@Z) referenced in function "void __clrcall `dynamic initializer for 'image2''(void)" (???__Eimage2@@YMXXZ@?A0x3871e7ff@@$$FYMXXZ)    C:\Users\tskhalil\Desktop\openvisionc-code-17-trunk\openvisionc-code-17-trunk\Sentry Project.obj    sentry 
Error   433 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__EncodePointer@4 referenced in function _pre_c_init C:\Users\tskhalil\Desktop\openvisionc-code-17-trunk\openvisionc-code-17-trunk\MSVCRTD.lib(crtexew.obj)  sentry
Error   434 error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__EncodePointer@4    C:\Users\tskhalil\Desktop\openvisionc-code-17-trunk\openvisionc-code-17-trunk\MSVCRTD.lib(atonexit.obj) sentry
Error   435 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _WinMain@16 referenced in function ___tmainCRTStartup C:\Users\tskhalil\Desktop\openvisionc-code-17-trunk\openvisionc-code-17-trunk\MSVCRTD.lib(crtexew.obj)  sentry
Error   436 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__IsDebuggerPresent@0 referenced in function ___raise_securityfailure    C:\Users\tskhalil\Desktop\openvisionc-code-17-trunk\openvisionc-code-17-trunk\MSVCRTD.lib(gs_report.obj)    sentry
Error   437 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _IsProcessorFeaturePresent@4 referenced in function ___report_gsfailure   C:\Users\tskhalil\Desktop\openvisionc-code-17-trunk\openvisionc-code-17-trunk\MSVCRTD.lib(gs_report.obj)    sentry
Error   438 error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _IsProcessorFeaturePresent@4  C:\Users\tskhalil\Desktop\openvisionc-code-17-trunk\openvisionc-code-17-trunk\MSVCRTD.lib(cpu_disp.obj) sentry
Error   439 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__QueryPerformanceCounter@4 referenced in function ___security_init_cookie   C:\Users\tskhalil\Desktop\openvisionc-code-17-trunk\openvisionc-code-17-trunk\MSVCRTD.lib(gs_support.obj)   sentry
Error   440 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__GetCurrentProcessId@0 referenced in function ___security_init_cookie   C:\Users\tskhalil\Desktop\openvisionc-code-17-trunk\openvisionc-code-17-trunk\MSVCRTD.lib(gs_support.obj)   sentry
Error   441 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__GetCurrentThreadId@0 referenced in function ___security_init_cookie    C:\Users\tskhalil\Desktop\openvisionc-code-17-trunk\openvisionc-code-17-trunk\MSVCRTD.lib(gs_support.obj)   sentry
Error   442 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__GetSystemTimeAsFileTime@4 referenced in function ___security_init_cookie   C:\Users\tskhalil\Desktop\openvisionc-code-17-trunk\openvisionc-code-17-trunk\MSVCRTD.lib(gs_support.obj)   sentry
Error   443 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__DecodePointer@4 referenced in function __onexit    C:\Users\tskhalil\Desktop\openvisionc-code-17-trunk\openvisionc-code-17-trunk\MSVCRTD.lib(atonexit.obj) sentry
Error   444 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "extern "C" void __stdcall Sleep(unsigned long)" (?Sleep@@$$J14YGXK@Z) referenced in function __catch$?_Initialize@LanguageSupport@<CrtImplementationDetails>@@$$FAAEXXZ$0    C:\Users\tskhalil\Desktop\openvisionc-code-17-trunk\openvisionc-code-17-trunk\MSVCMRTD.lib(mstartup.obj)    sentry
Error   445 error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __CorExeMain@0    C:\Users\tskhalil\Desktop\openvisionc-code-17-trunk\openvisionc-code-17-trunk\LINK  sentry`
```

i have these lib included in Linker>>Input >>Aditional dependencies
kernel32.lib
user32.lib
gdi32.lib
winspool.lib
comdlg32.lib
advapi32.lib
shell32.lib
ole32.lib
oleaut32.lib
uuid.lib
odbc32.lib
odbccp32.lib

any help please i need it for graduation project still two week only :(

Here is the code can any body tell me how to fix this class

```
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#if (defined(_WIN32) || defined(__WIN32__) || defined(__TOS_WIN__) || defined(__WINDOWS__) || (defined(__APPLE__) & defined(__MACH__)))
#include <cv.h>
#else
#include <opencv/cv.h>
#endif

#include "cvblob.h"

namespace cvb
{

  CvScalar cvBlobMeanColor(CvBlob const *blob, IplImage const *imgLabel, IplImage const *img)
  {
    CV_FUNCNAME("cvBlobMeanColor");
    __CV_BEGIN__;
    {
      CV_ASSERT(imgLabel&&(imgLabel->depth==IPL_DEPTH_LABEL)&&(imgLabel->nChannels==1));
      CV_ASSERT(img&&(img->depth==IPL_DEPTH_8U)&&(img->nChannels==3));

      int stepLbl = imgLabel->widthStep/(imgLabel->depth/8);
      int stepImg = img->widthStep/(img->depth/8);
      int imgLabel_width = imgLabel->width;
      int imgLabel_height = imgLabel->height;
      int imgLabel_offset = 0;
      int img_width = img->width;
      int img_height = img->height;
      int img_offset = 0;
      if(imgLabel->roi)
      {
    imgLabel_width = imgLabel->roi->width;
    imgLabel_height = imgLabel->roi->height;
    imgLabel_offset = (imgLabel->nChannels * imgLabel->roi->xOffset) + (imgLabel->roi->yOffset * stepLbl);
      }
      if(img->roi)
      {
    img_width = img->roi->width;
    img_height = img->roi->height;
    img_offset = (img->nChannels * img->roi->xOffset) + (img->roi->yOffset * stepImg);
      }

      CvLabel *labels = (CvLabel *)imgLabel->imageData + imgLabel_offset;
      unsigned char *imgData = (unsigned char *)img->imageData + img_offset;

      double mb = 0;
      double mg = 0;
      double mr = 0;
      double pixels = (double)blob->area;

      for (unsigned int r=0; r<(unsigned int)imgLabel_height; r++, labels+=stepLbl, imgData+=stepImg)
    for (unsigned int c=0; c<(unsigned int)imgLabel_width; c++)
    {
      if (labels[c]==blob->label)
      {
        mb += ((double)imgData[img->nChannels*c+0])/pixels; // B
        mg += ((double)imgData[img->nChannels*c+1])/pixels; // G
        mr += ((double)imgData[img->nChannels*c+2])/pixels; // R
      }
    }

      /*double mb = 0;
      double mg = 0;
      double mr = 0;
      double pixels = (double)blob->area;
      for (unsigned int y=0; y<imgLabel->height; y++)
    for (unsigned int x=0; x<imgLabel->width; x++)
    {
      if (cvGetLabel(imgLabel, x, y)==blob->label)
      {
        CvScalar color = cvGet2D(img, y, x);
        mb += color.val[0]/pixels;
        mg += color.val[1]/pixels;
        mr += color.val[2]/pixels;
      }
    }*/

      return cvScalar(mr, mg, mb);
    }
    __CV_END__;
  }

}
```

Here is The error

```
Error   4   error LNK2028: unresolved token (0A000A10) "extern "C" void
__cdecl cvError(int,char const *,char const *,char const *,int)" (?cvError@@$$J0YAXHPBD00H@Z) referenced in function "extern "C" struct CvScalar __cdecl cvBlobMeanColor(struct cvb::CvBlob const *,struct
_IplImage const *,struct _IplImage const *)" (?cvBlobMeanColor@@$$J0YA?AUCvScalar@@PBUCvBlob@cvb@@PBU_IplImage@@1@Z)    
C:\Users\tskhalil\Desktop\openvisionc-code-17-trunk\openvisionc-code-17-trunk\cvcolor.obj   sentry
```

Comment: Can you add the code (with includes & pragmas)?

Comment: You haven't mentioned what open source code library you are using.  You haven't mentioned how you are building the project, or by "the project" you mean some project included in the open source library.

Comment: i found a code for an open source project for tracking and i need it for my project i tried to build it using vs2013 
here u can find the code http://sourceforge.net/p/openvisionc/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/

Comment: the files that had this error are .obj file  
Error 398 error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual int __thiscall cv::_InputArray::type(int)const " (?type@_InputArray@cv@@UBEHH@Z) C:\Users\tskhalil\Desktop\openvisionc-code-17-trunk\openvisionc-code-17-trunk\   people.obj sentry

Comment: here is some of my includes and pragmas but not all because the code is really big 

#pragma once
#pragma unmanaged
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "header.h"
#include "cvaux.h"
#include "cxmisc.h"
#include "highgui.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

this include for one of the classes that has this problem